# Website screen capture from native application

Tags: c++, opengl, screenshot

I have a native C++ application built using using OpenGL (and openFrameworks as well in some core classes). I have been looking for a way to programatically take the screenshot of a website from this desktop application that is to happen on some interaction by the user and save it in a certain path on the computer.

I am fine with installing a separate application to issue commands to it somehow, a command line program, including a small API or library etc. but I have to stick to Windows for this purpose.

I won't be able to include another full framework such as Qt for this purpose (which I believe  gives the ability to take a screenshot from native application). I found some solutions for mac and linux but couldn't find anything for windows:

webkit2png : http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/
khtml2png : http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net etc.

Comment: (Why tag [qt] if you don't want to use that?)

Comment: @Mat: In the hope that `qt` guys would know an alternative to using WebView from their framework.